# HTML customized input mixing text and tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have been searching for a javascript plugin to customize edit of an input field... The basic idea is I would like to replicate some functionnality of slack or todoist input field which is a mix of text and tag recognition.

So let say I'm typing so following sentence :

@pierre for tomorrow please call back xxx

when typing @pierre I would like to recognise that it's being address to pierre and tag it up (and on click undo the recognition by the way) next task is due for tomorrow (or if I type 23/11 the day after) and xxx is a client of ours...

I would like to be able to screen live the text being written and if it match patterns or lists then I can tag it and assign...

In slack @ triggers a popup where I can select :
[image]

In todoist if I write tomorrow it is being detected and tag :
[image]

If I click the tag it will be untagged...

If I could only find an easy plugin in jquery that would be magnificent ! if not jquery I will try too :)

any help very welcomed

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You'd be better off posting a single question for a _single issue_ and then supplying a _coded example_ of what you've tried. We can assist you in a more technical capacity that way.

Comment: strange comment of yours... basically trying to find a solution to what I'm trying to do ! I have been searching out there and didn't find any solution reason why I'm posting...

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow provides solutions for _coding problems_ and does not offer advise or answers to multiple questions at once. We need _coded examples_ to provide you a solution. I think you might be better off asking the question on CodeProject or something similar if you do not have any code examples we can work off to help you :)

Comment: Regarding what others said about the question being subjective, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (and the rest of the links on the right side for that matter). In that link, paragraph 4, describes why your question is off topic. That said, you might find `typeahead` and `bootstrap-tagsinput` helpful in your research

Comment: @user1998000 This will help you https://github.com/yairEO/tagify 
It support mixing text and tags